# Using VBA, copy all formulas from one sheet to another and nothing else?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy all formulas from one sheet to another using VBA. I don't want to copy anything else than the formulas. What is a good way to do this?

To explain with an example,  if the source sheet contains:

```
formula value   value
blank   formula value
blank   blank   formula
```

and the target sheet contains:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

I want the target sheet to get the values:

```
formula 2   3
4   formula 6
7   8   formula
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, ady As String
    For Each r In Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        ady = r.Address
        r.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range(ady)
    Next
End Sub
```